# Support the community and promote SharePoint.SE

Tags: discussion, conferences

The most recent StackExchange blog post, [Supporting Community Conferences](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/), talks about supporting community members in exchange for promoting the site... possibly even by subsidizing your trip to a conference!

> Now, it’s up to you to raise a discussion on meta to determine which
>   conferences, seminars, conventions, events, or meetups appeal to your
>   community and would be a good way to publicize how great your
>   community is to people who love this stuff as much as you do, but have
>   probably never heard of your site. Or Stack Exchange.

Which SharePoint events would appeal to you? Who would be interested in going/speaking?

Answer (score 3):

For UK readers, the next big thing happening here is SharePoint Saturday UK, on November 12th: http://sharepointsaturday.org/uk/default.aspx

Otherwise, the main conference for the UK is the European Best Practices Conference normally held in April: http://sharepointbestpractices.co.uk/

Comment: Yeah, SharePoint Saturday would be a good opportunity. Jim, can you have a word?

Comment: I have confirmation as of today by @dori that SE will cover my expenses for speaking at SPSUK

Comment: Awesome. Yeah, I was finishing up for a 2 week wedding vacation just after I posted that xD Also, I live like 10minutes from the venue, so it's better that someone else get the bonuses of representing SE from afar.

Comment: go for it! :-) you might get a badge that say "Bus ticket sponsored by SE" :-) Are you speaking at SPSUK?

Comment: Nope, on the organisers helping hand list though. Probably zooming about taking photos again.

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft SharePoint Conference 2011](http://www.mssharepointconference.com/)

> Microsoft® SharePoint® Conference 2011 is
>   the most comprehensive event in the world dedicated to SharePoint and
>   related technologies.

I think this is **THE** conference to go to for SharePoint.

Comment: Maybe we should have an informal meetup - SharePint Overflow!

Answer (score 2):

[SharePoint Saturday the Conference DC](http://www.spstc.org/Pages/default.aspx) is happening state side next week.  Apparently they are expecting over 3000 attendees.

I belive [Chris Beckett](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/2498/chris-beckett) has a session there.

Answer (score 0):

Your local SharePoint Users Group. For example, the [St. Louis SharePoint Users Group](http://www.stlsug.org/default.aspx).

I think this would be a great way to get more experts involved.